# Gmail Push Notifications and renewing watch

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am starting with the [Gmail push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push). I have a process with the following logic:

1. Call the watch api and store the historyId (this is done once)
2. When I receive a new notification, call the history list api with the last stored historyId
3. Once the messages have been retrieved, update the stored historyId with the notification historyId

The documentation recommends [renewing the watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch) every day. What I am unsure about is do I need to store the watch response historyId every time I renew the watch?

Comment: As per documentation, I think once per day is enough to call the watch. Since it was already stated [there](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch).

Comment: That I understand, my question is do I need to store the historyId in the watch response in this situation or can I discard it.